# Super User times out

Tags: bug, status-completed

When will Super User be accessible again?

Super User is not accessible right now. The other three sites work (Server Fault, Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow). Browser error message:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Traceroutes are listed below. Times are UTC+2.

---

Super User:

```
2010-04-09T15:04:31.48 C:\> tracert www.superuser.com

Tracing route to superuser.com [69.59.196.219]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  FWT [192.168.1.1]
  2   179 ms   149 ms   159 ms  10.66.37.66
  3   144 ms   160 ms   159 ms  10.66.37.65
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5   303 ms   348 ms   358 ms  10.66.9.5
  6   290 ms   329 ms   339 ms  10.66.11.2
  7   277 ms   329 ms   319 ms  te7-8.ccr01.sto01.atlas.cogentco.com [149.6.168.9]
  8   292 ms   359 ms   339 ms  te0-2-0-3.ccr22.ham01.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.48.157]
  9   298 ms   359 ms   377 ms  te3-2.ccr02.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.50.33]
 10   388 ms   448 ms   457 ms  te3-2.ccr02.ymq02.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.0.69]
 11   421 ms   468 ms   457 ms  te9-1.ccr01.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.30.238]
 12   413 ms   477 ms   469 ms  te0-4-0-0.ccr21.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.6.158]
 13   434 ms   488 ms   478 ms  te4-4.mpd02.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.130]
 14   467 ms   498 ms   500 ms  te7-3.ccr01.smf01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.14]
 15   483 ms   517 ms   518 ms  te4-1.ccr01.pdx01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.94]
 16   463 ms   508 ms   528 ms  38.104.104.98
 17   465 ms   528 ms   518 ms  PTLDORPBCR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.209]
 18   487 ms   538 ms   530 ms  vl16-eugnor53cr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.190]
 19   480 ms   528 ms   518 ms  206-192-226-18.lsnetworks.net [206.192.226.18]
 20   467 ms   538 ms   519 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 21   467 ms   517 ms   519 ms  vlan5-cvo-colo2.peak.org [69.59.218.226]
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

Stack Overflow:

```
2010-04-09T15:08:34.12 C:\> tracert www.stackoverflow.com

Tracing route to stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  FWT [192.168.1.1]
  2   368 ms   338 ms   330 ms  10.66.37.66
  3   387 ms   357 ms   358 ms  10.66.37.65
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5  1462 ms   349 ms   357 ms  10.66.9.5
  6   275 ms   350 ms   327 ms  10.66.11.2
  7   286 ms   328 ms   329 ms  te7-8.ccr01.sto01.atlas.cogentco.com [149.6.168.9]
  8   287 ms   338 ms   350 ms  te0-1-0-2.ccr22.ham01.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.51.193]
  9   317 ms   349 ms   368 ms  te3-2.ccr02.ams03.atlas.cogentco.com [130.117.50.33]
 10   396 ms   439 ms   447 ms  te4-2.ccr02.ymq02.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.0.74]
 11   405 ms   457 ms   467 ms  te8-7.ccr01.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.28.1]
 12   413 ms   468 ms   468 ms  te0-0-0-3.ccr21.mci01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.2.217]
 13   740 ms   277 ms   408 ms  te4-4.mpd02.den01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.7.130]
 14   276 ms   299 ms   298 ms  te7-3.ccr01.smf01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.3.14]
 15   290 ms   296 ms   499 ms  te4-1.ccr01.pdx01.atlas.cogentco.com [66.28.4.94]
 16   336 ms   338 ms   340 ms  38.104.104.98
 17   473 ms   516 ms   539 ms  vl-12-PTLDORPBCR01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.21]
 18   477 ms   537 ms   549 ms  vl16-eugnor53cr01.lsnetworks.net [216.110.192.190]
 19   478 ms   527 ms   518 ms  206-192-226-18.lsnetworks.net [206.192.226.18]
 20   476 ms   518 ms   539 ms  ge-0-0-0-cvo-core2.peak.org [69.59.218.197]
 21   475 ms   529 ms   537 ms  vlan5-cvo-colo2.peak.org [69.59.218.226]
 22   485 ms   528 ms   549 ms  stackoverflow.com [69.59.196.211]

Trace complete.
```

Comment: I'm waiting for answers for my question :((

Comment: Bigger question is, what happens if we migrate a question to SU during the downtime? :-)

Comment: That one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607780/sending-image-embedded-in-the-body-of-the-email-body-in-blackberry could do, it would get closed on SU anyway :-]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a minor server problem -- we're having the datacenter reboot that server now.

Long story, but a reboot should fix it.

Comment: It's Friday, perfect time for a long story!

Comment: A minor server problem with a major service impact.  Good to have SU back up!

Comment: we have spent weeks on this and think it is a bug in Windows Server 2008 R2's networking stack. We have to call MSFT support.

Comment: @Jeff: Sounds like material for a codinghorror post... *hint* *hint* :)